# Get the number of push notifications in user's NSUserNotificationCenter

Tags: macos, push-notification, badge

I am working on a Mac application that receives push notifications, and I would like to keep the badge number in sync with the number of messages in the user notification center.

When I poll the NSUserNotificationCenter's delivered and scheduled notifications, I receive 0 objects even though I have 2 messages visible in my notification center.

```
NSMutableArray *allNotifications = [NSMutableArray array];
[allNotifications addObjectsFromArray:[[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] deliveredNotifications]];
[allNotifications addObjectsFromArray:[[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] scheduledNotifications]];
```

Is there a different notification center for push notifications?